# How to flip bit fields in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to flip a bit field in SQL Server using an update query, that is, I want to make all the 0's into 1's and vice versa. What's the most elegant solution?

There doesn't seem to be a bitwise NOT operator in T-SQL (unless I'm missing something obvious) and I haven't been able to find any other way of performing the update.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You don't need a bitwise-not for this -- just XOR it with 1 / true.

To check it:

```
select idColumn, bitFieldY, bitFieldY ^ 1 as Toggled
from tableX
```

To update:

```
update tableX
set bitFieldY = bitFieldY ^ 1
where ...
```

[MSDN T-SQL Exclusive-OR (^)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: Great! Thanks for that - it works like a charm. I obviously need to learn a bit more about how to use binary operators

Comment: Another article: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/how-to-flip-a-bit-in-sql-server-by-using

Comment: Keep in mind that `bitFieldY ^ 1` will return an `int`, so if you need it to be a `bit` again, `CAST` or `CONVERT` it back to `bit`.

Answer (score 57):

Why not a simple `bitfield = 1 - bitfield`?

Comment: An ingenious and elegant approach, especially for a one-off query, where readability isn't important.

Comment: @Billious, and GBN you both are right, but I guess Austin's reply is good enough to understand the objective in its clear meaning. Flipping a bit with 1-x will confuse the new commers and hence is not a proper way of achieving it. I also agree that there will be more than one approaches of doing something but if there is a recommended way to do it we should go with it, which is presumably faster than a non-recommended approach.

Comment: Maybe for a nullable `bitfield`, an approach would be `bitfield = 1 - ISNULL(bitfield,0)`.  See [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the documentation.

Comment: @UweKeim  Personally, I don't use NULLable bit. Never really needed 3 states for bit

Comment: Thanks, @gbn. I sometimes do when having a legacy table where I add a new bitfield column later on. (Probably this is solvable much more elegant with more knowledge).

Answer (score 31):

Another way is

```
DECLARE @thebit bit = 1, @theflipbit bit

SET @theflipbit = ~ @thebit

SELECT @theflipbit
```

where "~" means "NOT" operator. It's clean and you get a good code to read.
"negate the bit" is even cleaner and it does exactly what the "NOT" operator was designed for.

Comment: Same idea but turns NULLS to true: UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET BIT_FIELD= IIF(BIT_FIELD IS NULL,1,~ BIT_FIELD)

Answer (score 20):

I was pretty sure that most SQL flavors had a bitwise NOT, so I checked and there does [appear to be one in TSQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173468.aspx).

From the documentation, it's the character `~`.

Comment: SELECT ~MyBitField from MyTable

In other words

Update MyTable set MyBitField = ~MyBitField

Answer (score 14):

```
UPDATE tblTest SET MyBitField = CASE WHEN MyBitField = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

It's bland but everyone will understand what it's doing.

EDIT:

You might also need to account for nulls as suggested in the comments.  Depends on your req's of course.

```
UPDATE tblTest SET 
   MyBitField = CASE 
      WHEN MyBitField = 1 THEN 0 
      WHEN MyBitField = 0 THEN 1
      ELSE NULL -- or 1 or 0 depending on requirements
   END
```

Comment: This will set MyBitField to 1 when it starts as NULL. Not exactly flipping the bit.

Comment: I figured it was self evident... but I'll add info about handling nulls just in case.

Comment: I would tend to agree with some of the other guys and go for the ~ or the "^ 1 ".  Especially if this is a one time thing (just seems cleaner).  However, if this a something that will stick around and maintainability is in question, this solution is certainly the most straight forward.

Comment: In my case this was a one-off query, so maintainability wasn't an issue, but yes, this would have worked equally well. I actually had written a similar query but had trouble getting the CASE statement to work properly. I now realise it was a simple syntax error. D'Oh!

Comment: I like this one too. I find sometimes that if I come across a symbol I don't understand in code that if can be harder to work out the coder's intentions. But this is obvious.

Answer (score 12):

A simple bitwise NOT operator (~) worked for me in SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0

In the update clause inside your T-SQL -

```
        Update TableName
        SET    [bitColumnName] = ~[bitColumnName],
               ....
        WHERE  ....
```

Hope this helps

Ref - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
UPDATE mytable SET somecolumn = 
  CASE WHEN somecolumn = 0 THEN 1 
       WHEN somecolumn IS NULL THEN NULL
       WHEN somecolumn = 1 THEN 0
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

query (vb)

```
x = "select x from table"
```

update (vb)

```
"update table set x=" Not(x*(1))
```

Comment: this is not going to work even in vb and the question is for t-sql